# How can I make a full width and height image inside a column with text, overlay and rounded corners in visual composer?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

I know that questions like this aren't welcomed here but I'm struggling a long time to find a solution for making an image with overlay and rounded corners and a text inside it in visual composer. I'm pretty sure that this example was actually made in visual composer but I can figure out what element or combination of elements it was used here.
Please help me. 
Thanks.
[image]

Please note that this is not a full width row but a 1/2 column.

Comment: this very short video, should help you with the background image : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zvLtpksu1o - as for the rounded cornors, you can add an extra class to your element, and style that class with border-radious

Comment: So, the example you have posted here, should be something like a 1/2 column with a background picture, a text field with padding - and done? right?

Comment: and also rounded corners and a alpha color overlay

Comment: I watched the clip and it helps to make the background image for the column but how can I get those additional properties like rounded corners and color overlay on it?

Comment: when you go into edit on the column, in the bottom, you can add an extra class - which you can style whatever way you want in your css

Comment: Thank you very much I found it and it's working. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: No thanks necessary, only upvotes.

Comment: Post an answer and I'll UW it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an background image to your column - edit you column, and go into the tab "design options", here you can set the background image.

To add padding to your text box inside - Do the same and add padding.

To get the round corners - add an extra css class and style that in style.css with border-radius